# WCF The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http

Tags: wcf, iis

SSL offloading is enabled on our load balancer , all communication from the load balancer to the webservers is done in HTTP. We will not be enabling https on the service and security is set to None in the bindings. When I try testing with my client through the load balancer I run in to the error of "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http" . It almost looks like https all the way to the web server/WCF when it should not be the case. I tried custom bindings and everything else that I can find on google with no luck. Any one else run in to a similar issue . I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Sgasenan, what's the framework version of you WCF server?

Comment: I am using version 4.5. I was able to resolve the issue with the WCF extras dll.